# Cannot animate rotation of object along global Z

Tags: animation, transforms, keyframes

I would like to animate a rotation of the key on a vertical Z axis without changing its current position, like this:

[image]

When I press <kbd>R</kbd> then <kbd>Z</kbd>, the key rotates the way I want it to in the animation. I tried changing the Rotation Order, and applying Scale/Location/Rotation, and it didn't work.

However, when I keyframe the start and end point (<kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> 360º), the resulting animation makes the key spin in a different direction.

Here are my Transform settings:

[image]

Blend file:

[image]

Comment: @cegaton see my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an empty (null) object controlling the rotation for your key object.

[image]

Animate the rotation for the empty and the object will follow.

[image]